# How to make exfat appear as a disk on Computer (RedHat 6)

Tags: filesystems, rhel, fstab, uuid, exfat

I have a redhat 6 on 1TB HDD and another 1TB HDD with exfat format, anyway on Computer I can find the drive where redhat installed but not the exfat drive.

I do add a line to /etc/fstab for auto mount on specific directory but I am looking for to things:
1. Add xfat HDD in Computer as would be seen on Windows or MacOS
2. exfat partions UUID to put in /etc/fstab since using /dev/sdb1 is not convenient if the HDD removed temporary and flash drive added.

Comment: Please edit to show "what you have tried": how would you look for a UUID for a more well-supported partition type, and what does that method show for your exfat one?  If in doubt I would look at `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/`, because I assume that's exactly what `mount` does.

Comment: I assume you use the default RHEL6 desktop option which would be GNOME - It is arguably more useful for others if you edit your question to show the version of GNOME you are using...  More specifically, `rpm -q nautilus` will show the version of the GNOME file browser.  Or you can look in Help -> About for the version number, when you clicked on Computer.

Comment: Also you need to show the exact `fstab` line you used.  On my version of GNOME, I think the partition should usually show up if you have permission; this permission can be granted by the `user` or `users` option in `fstab`.

Comment: You should read this link: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/70050